# Preload high resolution image in hidden electron browser window

Tags: javascript, image, electron, paint

I have a hidden electron browser window which acts as a photoviewer for the main app.

Whenever users open a high resolution image it would take some hundred milliseconds to paint that image.

How to mitigate the needed duration to paint the high resolution photo on photoviewer ?

Answer (score 1):

The time required to paint a picture with a certain resolution depends mainly on the performance of the user's device.

But you can use the following method to make users feel that it is faster：

Load a low resolution image or a loading image first, and replace it when the high resolution image loaded.